# How can a ContextMenuToolStripItem be displayed, without doing it programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I've taken over a project, which contains some `UltraWinGrid` controls on some of the forms.

On one of the original forms which has been there since before I took on the project, there is a `ContextMenuStrip`, which has just one `ContextMenuToolstripItem` on it, captioned 'Default for Column'.

This `ContextMenuStrip` is hidden by default, however, when the user right-clicks on the `UltraGrid`, the `ContextMenuStripItem` is displayed on the grid (rather than at the top of them form where the `ContextMenuStrip` is).

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour in a new form that I've added myself, however, after adding the `ContextMenuToolstripItem` in, I cannot get it to display when right-clicking my grid.

I've put a breakpoint on every subroutine in the in the older forms class, and none of them are triggered when right-clicking it.

Additionally I have also searched the class for `DefaultForColumnToolstripMenuItem`, and the only place it appears is in the `Click` event of the `ContextMenuToolStripItem` itself.

So, how else is it possible to show it when right-clicking the grid? I've copy and pasted the `ContextMenuStrip` from the old form onto the new form and still nothing occurred.

I'm assuming it's in a property somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: Check for a `ContextMenuStrip` property on the UltraWinGrid. You can set it in the designer and it will appear on right click without having to deal with the `MouseClick` handler, checking the mousebutton used, etc.

Comment: @ProGrammer Yep, that's done it! Thank you

Comment: I thought there might be a dupe for this question, but I can't find one, so I've put my comment into an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a `ContextMenuStrip` property on the `UltraWinGrid`. You can set it in the designer and your context menu will appear on right click without having to deal with the `MouseClick` handler, checking the mousebutton used, etc.